# Spring/REST Resource/Service scope

Tags: java, spring, rest, scope

I am trying to figure out what is the best "scope" for a java REST webservice using jersey and spring.

I have a class defined like so:

```
@Path("/mypath")
@Component
@Scope("request")  // Or should this be @Scope("singleton")
public final class MyResource {

}
```

What I want to know is, should this be defined as request or singleton scope.  I think it should be singleton scope because it is stateless.  My thought is that this would be better performance wise since it is only created once, not a big performance gain but a small one.

However, someone expressed concern that there could be a performance loss/hit with a singleton because it will have to handle the requests from every thread, but my thought is that since there is no locking/synchronization then each thread will be able to call the method without being blocked, so no bottleneck.

I guess my question is two pronged:

1. Is singleton scope the best scope for stateless web services
2. Is there a performance loss when using a singleton because it has to
   handle multiple threads at once?

Thanks.

Comment: I have nothing to cite, but I have used singleton, and it has been very performant. I believe that each thread/request can call the code concurrently.

Comment: Consult the [Jersey docs](http://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html). Resources are request-scoped by default.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that in the jersey docs, however, spring defaults to singleton.  So, when you are using spring and jersey which takes precedence?  I am using what seems to be a jersey implementation of Spring "com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet"